# Resolve, Incompatible types error, java 8

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I am trying to implement one logic using java 8 streams().

```
List<Persons> persons = logs.stream().map(l -> {
  return rules.stream().map(rule -> generator.apply(rule)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But I am getting:

> Incompatible type: Required List but collect was inferred to R, no instance of type 
>      List of List of Persons

Comment: `logs.stream().flatMap(l -> {
  return rules.stream().map(rule -> generator.apply(rule)));
}).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: After trying your answer, getting **Persons lower bounds List<Persons>**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If

```
l -> {return rules.stream().map(rule -> generator.apply(rule)).collect(Collectors.toList());}
```

produces a `List<Person>`, the outer `Stream` pipeline would produce a `List<List<Person>>`.

You need `flatMap` if you want a `List<Person>`:

```
List<Persons> persons = 
    logs.stream()
        .flatMap(l -> rules.stream().flatMap(rule -> generator.apply(rule).stream()))      
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Explanation:

`rules.stream().flatMap(rule -> generator.apply(rule).stream())` creates a `Stream<String>` and flat maps it to a `Stream<Persons>`.

`.flatMap(l -> rules.stream().flatMap(rule -> generator.apply(rule).stream()))` flat maps the elements of the outer `Stream` to a `Stream<Persons>`, which can be collected to a `List<Persons>`.

BTW, it's not clear how the input `logs` are related to the output, since you are ignoring the elements of the `logs.stream()` Stream in your mapping.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried your solution, but I am getting equality constraint: Persons lower bounds List<Persons>.

Comment: @mayankbisht can you tell me the type of `rules`, as well as the signature of the `generator.apply(rule)` method?

Comment: Sure, **rules** = List<String>, **generator.apply(rule)** = Function<String, List<Persons>>.

Comment: Sure, **rules = List<String>**  & **generator.apply(rule) = Function<String, List<Persons>>**

Comment: @mayankbisht are you saying that the type of `generator` is `Function<String, List<Persons>>`? (which means `apply` accepts a `String` and returns a `List<Persons>`)

Comment: @mayankbisht See edit. My original answer was wrong.